# Why do I get NAs from the following for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to write a for loop to normalize the vector x with 5 values. However, after running the following code, I get the first four values as NAs and the last value as expected. Can anyone point out what the problem is? Thank you in advance!

```
x <- c(8.58, 10.46, 9.01, 9.64, 8.86)
x_mean <- mean(x)
x_sd <- sd(x)
n_x <- numeric()
for(i in length(x)){
   n_x[i] <- x[i] - x_mean / x_sd 
}
print(n_x)
```

Comment: Should be `for(i in 1:length(x)){ n_x[i] <- (x[i] - x_mean) / x_sd  }` - note also the added parentheses.  Or you could just use `scale(x)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comments you have couple of typos in your post. Your code should work if you correct them. Apart from that you could do this in a vectorised way without the need of `for` loop.

```
x <- c(8.58, 10.46, 9.01, 9.64, 8.86)
x_mean <- mean(x)
x_sd <- sd(x)
n_x <- (x - x_mean)/x_sd
n_x
#[1] -0.9718658  1.5310215 -0.3993969  0.4393366 -0.5990954
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace replace `length` with `seq_along`:

```
x <- c(8.58, 10.46, 9.01, 9.64, 8.86)
x_mean <- mean(x)
x_sd <- sd(x)
n_x <- numeric()
for(i in seq_along(x)){
  n_x[i] <- (x[i] - x_mean) / x_sd 
}

n_x
```

```
-0.9718658  1.5310215 -0.3993969  0.4393366 -0.5990954
```

Edit:

You also had missing parenthesis in `x[i] - x_mean / x_sd`